# Static resources being incorrectly rewritten to front-controller index.php

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I've got a problem with rewriting urls. 
The following is happening:

```
http://www.example.com/scores
http://www.example.com/registreren
http://www.example.com/login
```

these urls will be redirected to `index.php?route=scores` etc

This is all working very well. But now I've got template files in a subdirectory like `images` and `stylesheet`. These files are in

- `template/css/style.css`
- `images/images.png` etc

now all those files are also being redirected to `index.php?route`.
I'm aware of the leading slash and all links to the files are absolute paths.

The following code is being used in the `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ index.php?route=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: For testing comment out your RewriteRule above and then try to click: [your css](http://www.bitterballenscore.nl/template/style.css)

Comment: The links to "your css" in comments below (and above) - that you say are being "redirected" - are missing the `/css` path segment as stated in the question?

Answer (score 1):

Try to add a RewriteBase with this code:

```
RewriteBase /
```

Depending on the server configuration it is possible that `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` contains a slash at the begining which would produce an absolute and not a relative path.

Comment: I tried to add the RewriteBase, Also doesn't work. The stylesheet is just beeïng redirected
[link](http://www.bitterballenscore.nl/template/style.css)

Comment: Try to pass as second parameter `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` and `echo` the value.

Comment: If possible you could also try to set the mod rewrite loglevel higher and post your log file.

Comment: The `RewriteBase` directive would only be required here if the `.htaccess` file was not in the document root or the `RewriteBase` directive had already been incorrectly set and needed "correcting". However, this does not appear to be the case as the OP had already stated that requests for these supposedly "static resources" were being rewritten to `index.php?route=` (like the other URLs) - when it should not be being rewritten at all. The desired behaviour is that these "static resources" should be _ignored_ by the front-controller.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
> ```

Providing the static resources are correctly referenced with root-relative (or absolute) URLs in the HTML source (and there is no conflicting `BASE` element) then these conditions should already exclude the static resources from being rewritten.

You could add a condition to your front-controller that excludes requests for specific file extensions (assuming your URLs that require rewriting do not also share these file extensions).

This would also be a recommended optimisation for any front-controller as it prevents unnecessary filesystem checks for static resources - which will simply default to a 404 if not found (rather than being routed through the framework).

For example:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(css|js|png|jpg|png|gif)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ index.php?route=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Only when the requested URL does not end in one of the stated file extensions will it perform a filesystem check and potentially rewrite the URL to `index.php` (the front-controller).